# We are Russian or We are Russians?

Tags: grammar

I am having an argument with someone over the following text:

"Please don't come into our home. We are Russian. We don't talk, we shoot"

He claims that saying "we are Russian" is grammatically incorrect in general and "we are Russians" should be used instead. I am 100% certain that in this particular context it makes more sense to say "we are Russian", rather than "we are Russians" but I am having a hard time convincing this person since we both aren't native speakers.

I appreciate your input :)

Comment: Either one.  There's only a slight difference in meaning.

Comment: The big difference is that the first is an adjective "Russian" and the second a noun "Russians."

Comment: For a case where the adjective and the noun differ, consider *We are Spanish* and *We are Spaniards*.